# How to return a value without terminating the function?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I am writing a telegram bot using https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot.

I started from the echo example and didn't want to go far from it: in other words, I want the bot code to only forward the text to another function, transform it and send it back.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Simple Bot to reply to Telegram messages
# This program is dedicated to the public domain under the CC0 license.

"""
This Bot uses the Updater class to handle the bot.
First, a few handler functions are defined. Then, those functions are passed to
the Dispatcher and registered at their respective places.
Then, the bot is started and runs until we press Ctrl-C on the command line.
Usage:
Basic Echobot example, repeats messages.
Press Ctrl-C on the command line or send a signal to the process to stop the
bot.
"""
from telegram import Updater
import logging
import process

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments bot and
# update. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def start(bot, update):
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id, text='Hi!')

def help(bot, update):
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id, text='Help!')

def echo(bot, update):
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text = process.do_something(update.message.text))

def error(bot, update, error):
    logger.warn('Update "%s" caused error "%s"' % (update, error))

def main():
    # Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("MYTOKEN")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.addTelegramCommandHandler("start", start)
    dp.addTelegramCommandHandler("help", help)

    # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dp.addTelegramMessageHandler(echo)

    # log all errors
    dp.addErrorHandler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until the you presses Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So, the `echo` function does just that.

Let's assume that process looks like this:

```
def do_something(text):
    return text+" bla bla bla"
```

Now this works. But what if I want to do something else and then write  back to the user after one hour in case some other data changed?

Is there a way to return some text without the user having to write back to the system again? Like putting the function on hold?

So, the interaction starts when the user writes to the system, and it can be alive for max 1h. I don't want to user a `tell(userid,text)` function. I have some feelings that async me be the right tool. Am I right ? It is completely obscure to me how it works.

Comment: i the code `process` is a module, not a function. Please clarify

Comment: maybe you can use `yield` in the function and keep returning altered text when the relevant events occur

Comment: use a generator or coroutine

Comment: you can use parallel execution of functions. For example, one function tracks the "enviroment", and if some trigger appears, it sends the signal to the other function to stop or to do smth else.